# Forwarding ssh agent to VS Code development container to access Github via SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I run on Windows and have used. Out of simplicity, I have been using HTTPS towards Github, which appears to be shared and setup on his own when spinning development containers in VS Code. *The credentials are shared*, as per https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container.

Lately I've started running projects using Terraform and for some reasons I'm only able to reference some of our internal modules hosted on Github with SSH-like URLs.

I've spent a long time trying to substitute the HTTPS setup for SSH on the dev container, without much success.

**Initially**

**On my local:**

$ cat .ssh/config

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
  ForwardAgent Yes
```

And I checked, the agent is running indeed. When checking the "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" on my local and the dev container, they point to different agents.

How do I get that dev container to use the forwarded localhost agent that is running and has my github key ?

Comment: Make sure your container is not running an ssh agent on its own. That could override SSH_AUTH_SOCK set by Remote-Containers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely not running one explicitly. VS Code doing its own thing likely.

Comment: VsCode Devcontainer is running an ssh-agent and both the host and dev container agents are pointing to different sock when echoed the env var $SSH_AUTH_SOCK. But, still vscode dev container is able to pull keys from host and work. How does it work?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you what you want to do is, clone *private* GitHub repositories from within a vscode *devcontainer* using HTTPS via `terraform init` WITHOUT the need of explicitly providing git credentials / being prompted for credentials for that --> since you have credentials cached in windows already.

As stated by the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container), in order to share credentials between containers / host-os, you need to either use

- SSH (vscode forwards local ssh-agent to container)
- a git credential-manager (for HTTPS)

A suitable credential manager is the (now) built-in [Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core).
Make sure to have *Git for Windows* version `>= v2.28.0 (July 28th 2020)`, see [Release Notes](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/main/ReleaseNotes.md).
**To use it, run this in a shell on windows:**

```sh
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

Then login to GitHub once by pulling/pushing/cloning a repository via HTTPS.
Git (gcm) will prompt you for credentials (Personal-Access-Token) which you can generate via `GitHub Website > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token` (make sure to enable repo permissions).

This was tested in a devcontainer with:
`Dockerfile`:

```
# [Choice] Ubuntu version (use hirsuite or bionic on local arm64/Apple Silicon): hirsute, focal, bionic
ARG VARIANT=focal
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:${VARIANT}

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
    unzip

# Terraform
ENV VERSION 1.0.5
ENV SHA256SUM 7ce24478859ab7ca0ba4d8c9c12bb345f52e8efdc42fa3ef9dd30033dbf4b561

RUN wget "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/$VERSION/terraform_${VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip" -O /tmp/bin.zip
RUN echo "$SHA256SUM  /tmp/bin.zip" | sha256sum -c && \
    mkdir /tools && \
    unzip /tmp/bin.zip -d /usr/local/bin
```

`devcontainer.json`

```json
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "runArgs": [
        "--init"
    ],
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "args": {
            "VARIANT": "focal"
        }
    },
    "settings": {},
    "extensions": [],
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

And terraform project definitions:
`main.tf`

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "aks" {
  source = "github.com/USER/REPO"
}
```

Make sure to use the [correct url syntax for git HTTPS terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/sources.html#github)

Comment: Now, when re-reading the title I think you're trying to get SSH working not HTTPS... lol

Comment: If that is the case, you can just volume-mount your private key into the devcontainer and add it to the containers ssh-agent

Answer (score 1):

type 'Open SSH Configuration File' in the cmd pallet, it lets you select from a list of files.

Comment: The container does not appear to be able to read this file, which I suppose makes sense as the local home directory is not necessarily mounted

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I was able to get a devcontainer working with installed private repositories by using `"initializeCommand"` to first build my dev container like so:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default -t my-image:latest <path to container>
```

The --ssh default wont work for windows out of the box but you could manually specify it. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).

In your Dockerfile, I also needed prepend your git clone with the `--mount=type=ssh`.

In the docker-compose that I route to from the `devcontainer.json` I swapped from a build to using a pre-built image:

```
services:
  app:
    image: my-image:latest
```